# React Redux - Multitenancy approach (Saas model)

Tags: reactjs, redux, multi-tenant, react-redux

Lets say we want to have one instance of the application and multiple tenants trying to access same features but also have some level of customisation and of course data isolation. In short Basic SaaS model.

Tenants will probably be identified by subdomain/domain and/or by querystring.

So the main question (which is rather specific):

#### What are common approaches onto implementing a multitenant environment using React + Redux ?

Thinking loud:

1. How to approach/structure the Application Store.
2. How to deal with tenant specific configurations
3. Do I need to have some sort of a TenantContext available somewhere at hand.
4. How to ensure proper level of isolation and avoid race conditions?
5. What else should be kept in mind while developing it?

Any thoughts, ideas, past experience, advice, are highly appreciated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

A typical Redux store usually only reflects persistent data, and contains application-specific data, like which tab is active or what is the value of that field. But in case of persistent data, that's an interesting question. I believe React and Redux are simply not for that. But even though, there's an interesting solution for that: [Relay](https://facebook.github.io/relay/) and [subscriptions](http://graphql.org/blog/subscriptions-in-graphql-and-relay/).

Relay connects your components to a GraphQL source of data (typically remote), and then you simply access props that are seamlessly injected into component and given values from the data storage. With subscriptions, any update in the data storage causes its delivery to a connected component via a subscription established between the app and the GraphQL server.

Now, you can add an extra layer for multitenancy and synchronize data between nodes on a lower level, completely unrelated to React. The only thing now is that you'll need to listen to every update and send subscription updates, and there's no nice "single-click" solution for that yet.

You can see [this discussion](https://github.com/facebook/relay/issues/541#issuecomment-170811176) to get an idea how you can update a subscription. Good thing is that, on the client-side, the app will simply react to updated props with a connected component being re-rendered with new props.

Comment: (somebody, please improve this answer once subscriptions in Relay become popular)